# How to access both child and parent controller in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have two directives, called `parent` and `child`. Both of them have controllers defined, which hold some functionality. For `child` directive we can:

- access `parent controller` with `require` property (`require: '^parent'`), thus receiving fourth parameter to our link function with its value: `function link(scope, elem, attrs, parentCtrl)`
- access `child controller`: without using `require`, fourth link parameter will be our childController.

So the question is: how can we reference *both* child and parent controllers in `child`'s link function? Here's a plunker with the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WzU6iJgf2zLLApFHeiEG?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an array to the 'require' property of your directive definition, which includes both your child directive, and your parent directive. The 4th parameter to your link function will be an array:

```
app.directive('childDirective', function() {
    require: ['childDirective', '^parentDirective'],
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
        var childCtrl = ctrls[0];
        var parentCtrl = ctrls[1];
        ...
    }
});
```